# Unpacking lists within a data frame into multiple TensorFlow inputs

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

So I have a pandas data frame similar to this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0,1,0] | 1 | 0 |
| [1,0,0] | 0 | 1 |

and I want to unpack it so that it becomes 5 columns as apparently `tensorflow` doesn't support nested lists. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a formatted example of your data? and also provide an explanation to what you mean with "multiple Tensorflow inputs"

Comment: @AloneTogether sorry about the formatting, didn't understand that it needed spaces but it's working now. For what I'm trying to achieve, I'm trying to convert col1 into something like col1-1, col1-2, col-3 etc. as 3 new columns, because TensorFlow doesn't really like there being columns of integers and lists at the same time.

Comment: @AloneTogether yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merging the lists with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': [[0,1,0], [1,0,0] ], 'col2': [1, 0], 'col3': [0, 1]})

df['col1-1'], df['col1-2'], df['col1-3'] = zip(*list(df['col1'].values))
df = df.drop('col1', axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
   col2  col3  col1-1  col1-2  col1-3
0     1     0       0       1       0
1     0     1       1       0       0
```

Or with `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': [[0,1,0], [1,0,0] ], 'col2': [1, 0], 'col3': [0, 1]})

col1 = np.vstack(df['col1'].values)
col23 = df[['col2', 'col3']].values

data = np.concatenate([col1, col23], axis=-1)
print(data)
```

```
[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1]]
```